# Is it possible to discover all types and functions in a package using reflection?

Tags: go

Is it possible to get all the types and functions defined in a package using reflection at runtime? To make the question clear, in C# we can do this by using a method called `ExportedTypes` on an assembly and it returns a list of classes.

To be particular, what I need to do is to obtain a list of methods that have a particular return type while being able to invoke them dynamically when required.

Edit: I already know about the `AST` package, but I am asking in particular about the `reflection` package.

Comment: With reflection no, not at all. Functions absolutely not. Types would need to be explicitly registered upfront, then if you have those you can get their methods.

Comment: @mkopriva: So given a scenario where you need to identify certain functions and automatically call them when the app starts, that technically is not possible in Go, is that right? And the only way is to use the `parser` + `ast` packages to do static code generation instead?

Comment: The `reflect` package provides NO way to *"identify certain functions"*. The functions would have to be first registered explicitly, or, if what you need is to invoke them at program startup, they could be executed in the special, top-level `init()` func, or a call expression of a top level var declaration (`var _ = func() int { <your_thing>; return 0 }()`).

Comment: *"And the only way is to use the parser + ast packages to do static code generation instead?"* -- Note that not every executable program will also have the source code available. So while it's possible to do static analysis with `go/ast`&co., it will be possible only if the program doing the analysis has access to the source code. However you'll have more trouble executing the analyzed code.

Comment: Ideally, those packages that expect your program to execute their functions would, in one way or another, register those functions explicitly.

Comment: Perhaps if you'd clarify more precisely what it is that you are trying to do, it might become possible to provide more concrete suggestions.